# Golang worker pools - Queue new jobs from within jobs

Tags: go, worker

I am trying to concurrently build a tree from a collection of buckets and given that the worker pattern seems to be very popular in go, I tried applying it to my problem. Basically, I start a given number of workers and make them listen to a shared jobs channel. The first worker then receives the trees root node as the first job and fills it with relevant information, before branching and creating 2 more jobs. These jobs are then supposed to be distributed among the other workers, which would then recursively generate even more jobs until the whole tree is constructed.
A simplified representation of my naive approach looks similar to this:

```
func workers(count int) {

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(count)

    jobs := make(chan job)
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        go func() {
            // worker waits for job and then executes it
            for j := range jobs {
                processJob(j, jobs)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    // start with some initial job
    jobs <- job{}

    wg.Wait()

}

func processJob(j job, jobs chan job) {

    // jobs channel is closed when tree is finished
    if done {
        close(jobs)
    }
    // Do some more irrelevant stuff

    // sometimes 2 new jobs result from this one
    jobs <- job{}
    jobs <- job{}
    // but that doesn't work, if all workers try to send and no one receives

}
```

The problem is, that I can't add 2 new jobs from within 1, because at some point every worker would be busy trying to send jobs to the channel and no worker would be on the receiving end.

Can anyone point me into the direction of an elegant solution, or is my whole approach to the problem wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the current worker if no other worker is ready to process a job:

```
func doJob(j job, jobs chan job) {
    select {
    case jobs <- j:
    default:
        // Send to jobs was not ready, do the job
        // in the current worker.
        processJob(j, jobs)
    }
}
```

Replace the send statement `jobs <- job{}` with the call `doJob(job{}, jobs)`.

Use a buffered channel to keep workers busy:

```
jobs := make(chan job, N)
```

Tune `N` up until you find a value where the workers are mostly busy. A good starting value for `N` is `count`. This tuning is not required to prevent deadlock. The program does not deadlock when N is equal to zero.

Comment: (speaking from experience here), I think anyone should be careful using the "tune up N" approach, as for many classes of recursive problems, you can't actually pre-determine a safe value that is guaranteed not to deadlock. Even for **huge** values of N, you're setting yourself up for surprising, and likely unreported worker deadlocks in the future if your problem is exponential in nature.

Comment: I see what you mean. I had misunderstood the bottom part of your post as an alternative solution, rather than part of the same.